# How to set data to a sencha touch table

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Now I have a container that show as a table ,when I set data to this component ,the table show "undefined",the table is configed by tpl, and in tpl ,i set table line'value by {[values.xxx]}, but I run the code ,and show undefined in table's line , is someone meet this trouble before? The trouble is killing me..

Comment: You should give an example of your code.

Comment: Thanks buddy ,i solve the problem ,the mistake is caused by I didn`t use the container correctly . Thanks anyway!